# Importing csv file into Access DB

Tags: database, csv, ms-access, vba

it is easy to import csv file into Access database when source file has extension "CSV".
Problem is that we get our statistics' in files without extensions.

It is a bit annoying to change extension of source files every day. 
Does anybody know how to import file without extension? 
Or maybe there is a way around to add extensions to files in specified directory using VB ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you import files at the moment? There are many ways, e.g. using VBA or a saved import. Access Text Import is not restricted to .csv files.

Comment: @MP24 that is the point. When you try to do "External data -> text file" the wizard wont see files without extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can just enter `*.*` into the File Selector dialog in the Import Text wizard. Then you'll see all files, no need to rename anything.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions likely vary from version to version.
I had some trouble with this in Access 2010.  In the open dialog, you may select "All Files" to open nonstandard file extensions.  However, this often doesn't work since Access is not smart enough to know what format the file is in.

Luckily, you can change the drop down to "Text Files" and the file name you selected is preserved.  Even though the file does not appear in the file list, clicking Open uses the file name provided in the text box.

Similarly, navigating to the folder and manually typing in a file name while the correct file format is selected works for opening any type of non-standard extension.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306144) is a KB article containing workarounds in MS Access 2000.